# Android Service runs on which thread and how

Tags: android-service, android

I just wanted to know that on which thread the service runs? I'hv heard that it run in the main thread of their hosting process. If this is true then **why doesn't it blocks **UI****, and even if application exits the service continuous to run in background. Please help me in this. Again What am i asking is **service runs on main thread then why doesn't it blocks UI(ANR) ?**
    Answers will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Log.d("~~~","thread id="+Thread.currentThread().getId()+"  name="+Thread.currentThread().getName());
```

It prints the name and the numeric id of the thread.

PS Use `android.os.Process.myPid()` to get the process id.

Comment: I am not asking that i'm asking if it runs on main thread then why doesn't it blocks UI(Application Not Responding).

Answer (score 0):

If you carefully read the Android Documentation, you can find that : 
"Note that services, like other application objects, run in the main thread of their hosting process."

If you want your Service to run in a new Thread, you have to create that Thread yourself (or you may take a look at IntentService).